# VbScript Deserialize JSON

Tags: json, vbscript

Using the "ASPJSON" library - http://www.aspjson.com/

I am attempting to get to the "emailAddress" value in the following JSON string

```
{
"result": {
"lead": [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "emailAddress": "mickey@mouse.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "emailAddress": "mini@mouse.com"
  }
]
},
"error": null,
"id": "1"
}
```

I am having problems getting to the value using loops, which I believe is the only way to pul out the 2 email addresses.

This is the code I have so far:

```
For Each result In oJSON.data("result")
    Set this = oJSON.data("result")
        For Each lead in this("lead")
            Set this2 = oJSON.data("active").item(lead)
            response.Write("lead") & "<br>"
        Next
Next
```

When I commend out the line

```
Set this2 = oJSON.data("active").item(lead)
```

I get 2 lines written by the response.Write so I believe I have got down to the right "level"

But I have failed trying to pull out the values.

The example given by the author of the library looks like this:

But I have been unable to get it to do what I need:

The example JSON:

```
{
"firstName": "John",
"lastName" : "Smith",
"age"      : 25,
"address"  :
{
"streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
"city"         : "New York",
"state"        : "NY",
"postalCode"   : "10021"
},
"phoneNumber":
[
{
    "type"  : "home",
    "number": "212 555-1234"
  },
  {
    "type"  : "fax",
    "number": "646 555-4567"
}
]
}
```

And the code example is:

```
<!--#include virtual="/aspJSON1.17.asp" -->
<%
Set oJSON = New aspJSON

'Load JSON string
oJSON.loadJSON(jsonstring)

'Get single value
Response.Write oJSON.data("firstName") & "<br>"

'Loop through collection
For Each phonenr In oJSON.data("phoneNumber")
Set this = oJSON.data("phoneNumber").item(phonenr)
Response.Write _
this.item("type") & ": " & _
this.item("number") & "<br>"
Next

'Update/Add value
oJSON.data("firstName") = "James"

'Return json string
Response.Write oJSON.JSONoutput()
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working!

```
For Each result In oJSON.data("result")("lead")
Set this = oJSON.data("result")("lead").item(result)
        response.Write this.item("emailAddress") & "<br>"
Next
```